# Refactoring Static Methods to Extension methods using Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, refactoring, visual-studio-2019

Is there a refactoring available to Refactor Static Methods to Extension methods using Visual Studio 2019 C#?
for example I have `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( xxx );`
in too many places, (1000+ ), I would like to refactor to the extension Method `xxx.HasValue();` instead.

**Edit:** PS: I have the extension method `bool HasValue(this string);` , just that everywhere in the code people have used `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: Did you try to call&return `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( xxx )` in extension method?

Comment: So you want a tool that will automatically turn `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( xxx );` into the extension method `xxx.HasValue();` the answer is no, of course not, they have a completely different signature/name . However you can create them if you like

Comment: @KyleWang : yes, that is what the HasValue extension method is.

Comment: @TheGeneral : Updated the post, see if it answers what you asked.

Comment: @jimjim  What I mean is why not `return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);` in  `HasValue` derectly.

Comment: @KyleWang : yes, that is how HasValue is implemented. But people has already previously used !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace everywhere in solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now you want to replace all `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)` with `str.HasValue()`? Maybe you can use regex to achieve it.

Press `Ctrl + F` to open `Find&Replace` and check `Use Regular Expressions`

[image]

Next, input `(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace\((?<name>".*")\))` into `Find...`,

and `${name}.HasValue()` into `Replace...`.

Then click `Replace All`.

For more info, you can refer to [Use regular expressions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, a refactoring would have been nice, but this will do the job nicely! It is a very nice example of how to use Regex replace.